# JavaScript Paging

Tags: php, pagination

I have the java and everything set up, but it's not paging. It shows the pagination page links but it doesn't limit it. Here is what I have:

```
 <div class="pagination-holder clearfix" style="float: right;">
<div id="compact-pagination" ></div></div>
</div>
<div class="pagination-holder clearfix" style="float: right;">
<div id="compact-pagination" style="float: right;"></div></div>
<div id="compact-pagination" style="float: right;"></div>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#compact-pagination').pagination({
    edges: 2,
    currentPage: 1,
    hrefText: "#page-",
    prevText: "Prev",
    nextText: "Next",
    items: <?  echo $count; ?>,
    itemsOnPage: 2,
    cssStyle: 'compact-theme'
    });
});
</SCRIPT>
```

Then my php here.

So why won't it limit?

Link: http://flaviusmatis.github.com/simplePagination.js/

Php:

```
<?php   $sql = "SELECT
        *
    FROM
        users
    ORDER BY user_id";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result)
{
echo 'The category could not be displayed, please try again later.' .  mysql_error();
}
else
{
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{header('/');
    echo 'This category does not exist.';
}
else
{
    //display category data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
   ?>

 <ul class="memberlist">
        <li>  <div id="memberlist" style="float: left; width: 300px; margin-left: 11px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid #CCC; border-radius:7px; background-color:#666;padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;">
<div id="memberlist_top">
    <div id="memberlist_avatar">
        <img src="<?php echo $row['avatar'] ?>" style="border: 1px solid #CBCBCB; padding: 3px; width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
    </div>
    <div id="memberlist_top_right">
        <p id="memberlist_username"><a href="/index.php?page=user&id=<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['user_name'] ?></a></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><img src="<?php echo$row['site_rank_image']?>"</p>
        <p style="text-align: center;" id="ml_rep"> Reputation: 0 </p>
        <p id="ml_posts">Post count: <?php echo $row['post'] ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix" style="height: 5px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="memberlist_bottom">
    <p id="ml_bottom_p"><img src="template/images/layout/icon.png" style="vertical-align: middle" /> Date Registered: <span id="ml_bottom_span"><?php echo date(" F j, Y, g:i A", strtotime($row['user_date']))?> </span></p>
    <p id="ml_bottom_p"><img src="template/images/layout/icon.png" style="vertical-align: middle" /> Last online: <span id="ml_bottom_span"><?php echo date(" F j, Y, g:i A", strtotime($row['dt']))?> </span></p>
    <p id="ml_bottom_p" style="width: 284px; height: 30px; overflow-x: hidden; cursor: pointer;" title="Coming Soon"><img src="template/images/layout/icon.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" /> Last Activity: <span id="ml_bottom_span" style="text-decoration: underline;">Coming Soon</span></p>
    <p id="ml_bottom_p"><img src="template/images/layout/icon.png" style="vertical-align: middle" /> Is online now: <span id="ml_bottom_span"> <? if($row

['online'] == 1) {  // checks to see if the user allows their email to be shown, where '1' means they allow it to be shown
echo'Yes';
} else {
echo'No'; // if they allow it, it displays their email
} ?> </span></p>
</div>
</div> </li>
</ul>   
<? }}}?>
```

Comment: I really hope you meant to say javascript and not java. A link to the plugin would help too.

Comment: What is `pagination`?  That's not part of the jQuery/UI core.  What is your PHP code?  We can't tell you why it won't limit if we have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: Did you include jQuery and whatever plugin it is you're using correctly.

Comment: @RocketHazmat is correct. You need to show your PHP which responds to the pagination parameters, and you need to link us to the plugin you're using.

Comment: you need to do the 'limiting' on the backend

Answer (score 0):

How To Use

Step 1: **together with JQuery**, include jquery.simplePagination.js in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to/jquery.js"></script>
```